# Creating list workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have two lists(Source and Destination) in SharePoint 2010. By using list workflow I created some columns in source list to destination list. This is fine for me it worked.

But, When users edit an item in the InfoPath, I don't see the edited item in the destination list. I am seeing two items in the destination. In short, If users edit an item in InfoPath, it automatically will be able to edit the destination list too . Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What does your workflow do?  Is it set to copy an item from one list to another?

Comment: Yes ! It copy one item from source to destination

Answer (score 1):

You can customize and open the list using info path. and then go to list workflow on your SPD and create a variable in the list workflow and also create item as soon as set item. I guess it help you